# How to diagnose which process causes system to hang when it's being put to sleep?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, sleep

I have a Windows 7 system with a strange problem: sometimes, when I try to put my computer to sleep, it hangs – the screen goes black, but the indicator lights stay active, and the CPU fan ramps up to max within a minute or so. There is no BSOD.

I know it's not a matter of waiting: there have been times when I hit the power button in the evening, only to come back in the morning with the fans still going on full blast.

This happens seemingly at random – perhaps 2 out of 5 times – and I cannot figure out a way to diagnose what might be causing the problem.

I tried running ProcessMonitor with the `/backingfile` option to [automatically write trace files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carloc/2008/10/31/how-to-automate-process-monitor/) while I put the computer to sleep, but it didn't work: procmon would stop writing logs before the hang happened, and because I had to hard-reset the system, its final log file would always be corrupt.

I suspect it might be related to VirtualBox or Vagrant, but I've been running VMs for years, and this problem is relatively recent. The only other culprit I can think of is an audio program called [Hear](https://www.prosofteng.com/hear-audio-enhancer/), which often crashes after the system wakes.

If it helps, the computer in question is a Dell Inspiron n5050. I'm skeptical of the expertise on the Dell forums, but I did find a [thread on a similar issue](https://www.dell.com/community/General/crash-after-sleep-close-lid/m-p/3948935), and have confirmed that "hybrid sleep" is disabled. All my drivers are up-to-date relative to [Dell's list](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-15-intel-n5050/drivers), so that seems to be a dead end.

How can I diagnose what's causing the system to hang when it's trying to enter sleep?

Comment: Anything in the event logs?

Comment: @Mokubai Good call. I see a lot of "Schannel" errors with alert code 70. Their details contain a ProcessID and TheadID. I'll try to reproduce the issue and record the PIDs of running processes before attempting sleep to cross-reference.